# Legend Not Showing in GGplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot seem to get the legend to display for this code, I can't figure out what is going on in my code.

Thanks in advance.

```
  ggplot(r, aes(x, value)) +
  geom_col(data = r, aes(x, value, fill = "Rain Forecast Information"), fill = 'blue', width = 0.6, alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_col(data = d, aes(x, value, fill = "No Forecast Information"), fill = "red", width = 0.6, alpha = 0.7) +
  labs(title = "Expected loss in US$ given milk quantity", x = 'Gallons Bought', y = "Expected Loss") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10, labels = c(1:10)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = 'darkgray'),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = 'darkgray'),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: Can you make your question self contained by including some sample data.

Comment: The issue is that you map on `fill` inside `aes()` but also set the fill color outside of `aes()`. Hence, the latter will override the aesthetic mapping and you will not get a legend. Drop `fill = "blue"` and `fill = "red"` from the geom and use `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))` instead to set your colors.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could provide the example data. Without data, I cannot test it on my side. You may want to try something like this:

```
ggplot(r, aes(x, value)) +
  geom_col(
    data = r, aes(x, value, fill = "Rain Forecast Information"),
    width = 0.6, alpha = 0.7
  ) +
  geom_col(
    data = d, aes(x, value, fill = "No Forecast Information"),
    width = 0.6, alpha = 0.7
  ) +
  labs(title = "Expected loss in US$ given milk quantity", x = "Gallons Bought", y = "Expected Loss") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10, labels = c(1:10)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Rain Forecast Information" = "red", "No Forecast Information" = "blue")) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "darkgray"),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = "darkgray"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )
```